# Using JavaScript's Reduce to create an array from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

So the following code is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
var arr = [{
    name: 'foo',
    amount: 2
}, {
    name: 'foo',
    amount: 4
}, {
    name: 'foo',
    amount: 6
}, {
    name: 'foo',
    amount: 1
}, {
    name: 'foo',
    amount: 5
}, ];

var newArr = arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a.push(b.amount);
}, []);
console.log(newArr); // which I'd expect to be [2, 4, 6, 1, 5]
```

But this errors: `Uncaught TypeError: Object 1 has no method 'push'`. I know I could do this with `.forEach()` but I'm wondering if it's possible with `.reduce()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `map`, not `reduce`:

```
amounts = arr.map(function(x) { return x.amount })
```

If you want `reduce`, it goes like this:

```
var newArr = arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
    a.push(b.amount);
    return a;
}, []);
```

The `reduce` callback is supposed to return the accumulator object.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of objects there. So of course the objects don't know the function push which can be only applied on arrays.
Even if those were arrays it would not work because push returns the new length of the array. You should use map instead of reduce to achieve what you want to do.